# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '&'

Tags: python, flask, deployment, jinja2

I am deploying my machine learning model locally and use flask for that. I have my main.html and app.py but when I try to run it in the console I get the Error message above.

I cannot find any "&" in both files which is why I cannot solve the problem.

I checked all files but could not find a char like "&" and the debug mode just raises the error which I mentioned.

This is the html form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
form {
    margin: auto;
    width: 35;
}
.result {
    margin: auto;
    width: 35;
    border: 1px solid 
}
</style>
<head>
    <title>Sales Prediction</title>
</head>
<form action="{{url_for('main')}}" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Input values:</legend>
        Week:
        <input name="week" type="number" required>
        <br>
        <br> Grad:
        <input name="grad" type="number" required>
        <br>
        <br> Preis:
        <input name="preis" type="number" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<br>
<div class="result" align="center">
    {%if result%}
        {%for variable, value in original_input.items()%}
            <b>{{variable}}</b> : {{value}}
        {%endfor%}
        <br>
        <br> Predicted number of sales :
            <p style="font-size:50px">{{result}}</p>
    {%endif%}
</div>
</html>
```

and this is the app.py:

```
import flask
import pickle
import pandas as pd

with open('model/model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

app = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if flask.request.method == 'GET':
        return(flask.render_template('main.html'))
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        week = flask.request.form['week']
        grad = flask.request.form['grad']
        preis = flask.request.form['preis']
        input_variables = pd.DataFrame([[week, grad, preis]],
                                       columns=['week', 'grad', 'preis'],
                                       dtype=float)
        prediction = model.predict(input_variables)[0]
        return flask.render_template('main.html',
                                     original_input={'week':week,
                                                     'grad':grad,
                                                     'preis':preis},
                                     result=prediction,
                                     )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

As soon as I run it in the console I get

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '&' at 250601

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace?

Comment: What do you mean with full stack trace? @dylanj.nz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There needs to be space separating the Jinja delimiters (`{{`, `{%`, etc.) from the code inside them.

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('main') }}" method=post>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Input values:</legend>
        Week:
        <input name="week" type="number" required>
        <br>
        <br> Grad:
        <input name="grad" type="number" required>
        <br>
        <br> Preis:
        <input name="preis" type="number" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<br>
<div class="result" align="center">
    {% if result %}
        {% for variable, value in original_input.items() %}
            <b>{{ variable }}</b> : {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <br> Predicted number of sales :
            <p style="font-size:50px">{{ result }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your help und the support. Unfortunately it is not working and I am getting the same error. Do you have another idea? :)

Comment: If you could add the error message then I can check.

Comment: It is still this here:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '&' at 250602


I can send you the files too if this might help

Comment: Do you have base.html or any other HTML/Jinja template file?

Comment: It is a base.html file. Downloaded it directly from Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: I have made a small change, Please check

Comment: The answer works in general but just not on my computer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I received this error because my text was being escaped before being sent to Jinja.  For example, it seemed that this particular text snippet was being sent to Jinja:

```
Vous pouvez vous connecter à {{track_url(account_url,'sign_in')|shorten_url}}
```

but this was actually what was sent:

```
Vous pouvez vous connecter à {{track_url(account_url,&#x27;sign_in&#x27;)|shorten_url}}
```

The `&` in the `&#x27;` triggered the error.

Once I replaced the escaped apostrophes with actual apostrophes, the error went away.

In your case, perhaps the `{{url_for('main')}}` is being escaped, which would result in something like `{{url_for(&#27;main&#27;)}}` or `{{url_for(&apos;main&apos;)}}` causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you can get this error with the @ symbol instead of the & symbol.

In my case I had some ASP.Net code in my flask app and the ampersand was actually the problem in the HTML file:

```
<p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, {{ @User.Identity.GetLogin()! }}</p>
```